# Unfollowing with the SoundCloud API

Tags: php, javascript, ruby, api, soundcloud

I am trying to find a way to unfollow users via the use of the SoundCloud API. I know there is documentation for following/commenting, but is there any way to unfollow any particular user you are following with the use of the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [read the documentation here](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#follow)

The API endpoint is:

```
DELETE /me/followings/3207
```

Where "me" is the user who authenticated through your app and 3207 is the user ID of the person they were previously following.  I'd put the proper client code but you've tagged this question both PHP and Ruby.

Comment: Currently, this appears to not work via the javascript API. despite a 200 code.